Angular 17 Service Does not maintain state on Route Change
Why does my Angular 18 Service not maintain state when there is a route change.  It appears that a new instance of the service is created with route change.  The service is created with @Injectable({ providedIn: 'root'})
I was expecting the service to maintain its state across components and routes.

Can you show your route command you're using to navigate?

Configure
Quote

Thank you, you led me to the answer the :

You must use  instead of       The href attribute is used for general-purpose navigation.  When you use href, it reloads the page. If you’re navigating in an Angular application using href, it will refresh page, losing the current state.   The routerLink directive is provided by Angular’s Router for navigating within the app without triggering a page refresh. It allows you to navigate w/o losing the state.
Angular apps are  (SPAs), and routerLink helps maintain the SPA behavior.
